# Cannot link package when building APK using react-native

Tags: android, react-native

My react native project won't build I get the error below.

I have recently changed the package name of my app, it runs fine using `react-native` `run-android`. However when I build my apk using `./gradlew assembleRelease`. I get the error. Any ideas?

> What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':react-native-youtube:verifyReleaseResources'.
>
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
>     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
>     error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored not found.
>     error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored not found.
>     C:\Users\Matt\sites\tcapp\node_modules\react-native-youtube\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values-v26\values-v26.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
>     C:\Users\Matt\sites\tcapp\node_modules\react-native-youtube\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values-v26\values-v26.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
>     C:\Users\Matt\sites\tcapp\node_modules\react-native-youtube\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values-v26\values-v26.xml:15: error: style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster' not found.
>     C:\Users\Matt\sites\tcapp\node_modules\react-native-youtube\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values-v28\values-v28.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
>     C:\Users\Matt\sites\tcapp\node_modules\react-native-youtube\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values-v28\values-v28.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
>     C:\Users\Matt\sites\tcapp\node_modules\react-native-youtube\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:2711: error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.
>     C:\Users\Matt\sites\tcapp\node_modules\react-native-youtube\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:2712: error: resource android:attr/font not found.
>     C:\Users\Matt\sites\tcapp\node_modules\react-native-youtube\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:2713: error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found.
>     C:\Users\Matt\sites\tcapp\node_modules\react-native-youtube\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:2714: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
>     C:\Users\Matt\sites\tcapp\node_modules\react-native-youtube\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:2715: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
>     C:\Users\Matt\sites\tcapp\node_modules\react-native-youtube\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:2796: error: resource android:attr/startX not found.
>     C:\Users\Matt\sites\tcapp\node_modules\react-native-youtube\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:2799: error: resource android:attr/startY not found.
>     C:\Users\Matt\sites\tcapp\node_modules\react-native-youtube\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:2802: error: resource android:attr/endX not found.
>     C:\Users\Matt\sites\tcapp\node_modules\react-native-youtube\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:2805: error: resource android:attr/endY not found.
>     C:\Users\Matt\sites\tcapp\node_modules\react-native-youtube\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:2813: error: resource android:attr/offset not found.
>     error: failed linking references.

Comment: check this issue: https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-youtube/issues/331